# How do I tell the difference between "two" and "too"?

Tags: pronunciation, intonation

If there's someone said **"I'm twenty"**, and another person replied to him **"I'm twenty too"**.
But I heard it **"I'm twenty-two"**.

Is there a way to tell the difference between the use of *two* and *too* in these two sentences?

Comment: I've made an edit here because there is more to speech than pronunciation. It's very likely that *two* and *too* are actually **pronounced** identically; and in fact I reckon that the difference is actually marked by how *twenty* sounds, but I'm not a phonologist. However, the question need not be limited to pronunciation.

Comment: Probably tone of voice, and choice of words. A native speaker would be aware that 'twenty too' mighe be heard as '22' and might say 'I am too', or place stress on 'twenty', and pause between 'twenty' and 'too'.

Comment: Basically, you apply your understanding of the context and the speaker's pronunciation quirks to make a judgement.  And, if all else fails, you ask.

Comment: I’ve known my wife over 25 years. When she agrees with someone and wants to supplement their point, she says, “And too, ...” Or maybe she says, “And (2), ...” I have no idea, and I’m not about to ask now.

Comment: If I were to have that conversation where somebody said "I'm seventy" and I said "I'm seventy too" I would put a short break between the words 'seventy' and 'too' and pronounce the word 'too' with a slight downward cadence . If I said "I'm seventy-two" there would be little or no break between 'seventy' and 'two' and I would pronounce the 'two' with a slight rising cadence and a bit of emphasis. I suspect that is fairly universal (at least among speakers of BrEng) but might be a little difficult for non-native speakers to detect. "I am also seventy" would remove ambiguity completely though.

Comment: After B says "I'm twenty too" there would be a pause while both of them realize it is ambiguous,  then B would say "I'm twenty also".

Comment: It's totally dependent on how the utterance is delivered.